# Can I ask this question?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, specific-question

I want to ask a question about the pros and cons of allowing users to define functions with the same name as built-in functions. For example, defining:

```
max(a, b) {
    if a > b return a;
    else return b;
}
```

as a repeat of the already existing max function in some languages.

Would such a question be on-topic for PLDI?

Answer (score 3):

This would be on-topic, as it's asking about design choices in a programming language.

It also seems fine to me quality-wise (but that's a more subjective matter). If it's clear, on-topic, and will likely benefit some language designers, chances are it's a good question.